# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'extractall' extracting zip from brute force

Tags: python, zip, brute-force

Am not sure why I am getting the following error, I know the password after brute forcing it earlier on yet won't let me extract the file.

Need to extract my file to the directory /tmp

So am I missing anything glaringly obvious?

Output error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/tmp/usercode.py", line 45, in <module>
myZip.extractall("/tmp",pwd = str(password))
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'extractall'
```

Code:

```
import zipfile
from zipfile import ZipFile
import zipfile

zf = zipfile.ZipFile('/tmp/myfile.zip')
for x in range(0,139):
  #Legacy for loop now
  password = "past"
  print(password)
  for filename in [ 'textinhere.txt' ]:
        myZip = "textinhere.txt"
        try:
                myZip.extractall("/tmp",pwd = str(password))
        except KeyError:
                print 'ERROR: Did not find %s in zip file' % filename
        else:
                print filename, ':'
                print repr(data)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are defining a string here:
`myZip = "textinhere.txt"`

`exctractall` is a method of the `ZipFile` class. So you need to construct an instance of `ZipFile` first, assuming this name is the file you wish to use as a path for the ZipFile instance:

`myZip = ZipFile("textinhere.txt")`

...Only then can you call `myZip.extractall(...`

Comment: Ahh yes, somehow the file isn't found when I know it's in the directory an ideas?

Comment: provide the absolute path to the file to be sure you are pointing to the proper location